# Is there a difference and if so what between apk files used in android and apk files used by alpine

Tags: android, apk, alpine-linux

The apk extension is used by android and alpine linux for packages, obviously they contain different things, and are consumed differently. Are they actually different formats though?
I suspect they are very different but others have claimed they are both just zip files with linux executables

Comment: Alpine APK v2 packages make use of [tar and gzip](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Apk_spec), so Android APK files and Alpine APK files have absolutely nothing in common except those three letters `apk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are very different formats. As noted in comments, one of the differences is the compression method. Android APK [is a zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apk_(file_format)#Package_contents) while Alpine APK is a [concatenation of 3 gzip streams](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Apk_spec#Binary_Format).

Another big difference is the way code is packaged. Android APK contains ['.dex' files with bytecode](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/dex-format) for [Android Runtime](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime). Alpine APK contains typical for Linux [ELF executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).